# Really Weird ASP.Net Reserved Request.Form key name

Tags: asp.net, forms, reserved-words

I seem to have stumbled across a really weird issue when posting a static HTML page to an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) page:

Example:

```
<form action="Kiosk.aspx" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="key" name="key" value="1234" />
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="download" />

<input id="btnGo" type="submit" value="Download" />

</form>
```

When I call it using

```
string strKioskKey = incomingWebContext.Request.Form["key"];
```

it always returns null - if I change both the parameters to "key1" it works sweet...

But the question is WHY? I have never heard of a reserved word for requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this. Your problem lies elsewhere.

You may wish to try and re-create the problem as a small standalone app, and see at what point you can reproduce it (run it locally, then on your dev/live environment).

Comment: Strange - Created a test project and it worked, so i forced a clean and rebuilt and it works... dam you visual studio gods...

thanks for taking the time to reply ;-)